# Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence of positive monotonically increasing random variables converging to $X$. Show $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}E(x_n)=E(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, proof-verification

I am hoping to get some verification of the below proof. I am worried that I am missing something conceptually.

That
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(x_n)\leq E(X)$ is clear since
$E(x_n)\leq x$ for any $n$. Here is a quick proof by contradiction:

Suppose for the sake of contradiction
$$
  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(x_{n})> E(X)\Rightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{N}
  \text{ s.t. } E(x_n)>E(x)
$$
a contradiction of our hypothesis.

Now, let's prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(x_{n})\geq E(x)$.

Let $F\subset \Omega$ the sample space on which our random variable is defined, $|F|=N<\infty$. Then
$$
    E(\chi_F)=\sum_{x_n^{-1}(\mathbb{R_+})\subset F}x_nP(x=x_n)
$$

Then, since $x_n(\omega)>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and any $\omega\in \Omega$,and $x_n$ is an infinite sequence, there is some $x_{n}(\omega)$ for some
$\omega\notin F$ and
\begin{align*}
  & E(\chi_F)\\[8pt]
  = {} &\sum_{x_n^{-1}(\mathbb{R_+})\subset F}x_nP(x=x_n)\leq
    \sum_{x_n^{-1}(\mathbb{R_+})\subset F}x_nP(x=x_n)+
    \sum_{x_k^{-1}(\mathbb{R_+})\subset \Omega-F}x_kP(x=x_k)\\[8pt]
    = {} &E(X_{k+N})
\end{align*}
Showing that $E(\chi_F)$ is dominated by the partial sum with $N+k$,
$E(X_{k+N})$ terms.
Then, since we can dominate any finite subset of the sample space by some
finite partial sum, it is clear that, since $X$ is defined on at most
all of $\Omega$, we can bound, for some $N(X)$
$$
  E(X)\leq E(X_{N(x)})\Rightarrow E(X)\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E(X_n)
$$